# AdvancedDataGrid - disable the header rollover and selection color

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, rollover, flex3

i used before a datagrid and fixed that issue by overriding the methods but now i have to move to advanced data grid and didn't find the answer yet, could any one help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file:

```
AdvancedDataGrid { /* or the stylename you're using for the ADG */
  /* other styles */
  headerStyleName: "myHeaderStyle";
  /* other styles */
}

.myHeaderStyle {
  up-skin: Embed(source="myADGHeaderSkin.swf",symbol="upSkin");
  over-skin: Embed(source="myADGHeaderSkin.swf",symbol="upSkin");
  selected-skin: Embed(source="myADGHeaderSkin.swf",symbol="upSkin");
}
```

Basically change whatever states you want to use the same skin as the up-skin.